# Vaadin session expire URL and redundant redirect

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, session-management, vaadin24

I configured my Vaadin `24.4.0.alpha1` application with the following:

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=30m   
vaadin.closeIdleSessions=true 


@Override
public SystemMessages getSystemMessages(SystemMessagesInfo systemMessagesInfo) {
    var messages = new CustomizedSystemMessages();
    messages.setSessionExpiredURL("/idle.html");
    return messages;
}
```

After 30 minutes of inactivity, the user is redirected to the 'idle.html' page. Everything is fine here. On this page, I suggest returning to the application by clicking the link https://example.com.

In most cases, everything works well, but sometimes I see a situation where, after clicking this link, the user is redirected to the site and then immediately back to the 'idle.html' page. After clicking the link https://example.com again, the user correctly transitions to the site.

Why could this be happening? Something, somewhere, may be cached, perhaps some cookies that I need to forcefully clear on the session destroy event or invalidate session.. etc?

I cannot consistently reproduce this issue right now, so I request your assistance in locating it

Comment: Is your app using VaadinWebSecurity and SSO?

Comment: yes,  I use Keycloak for SSO with Vaadin

Comment: Ok. Then I guess the following is possible. You have longer timeout for login token validity than session. Hence after session times out, user is automatically logged in. 
 VaadinWebSecurity  has a request cache, i.e. it caches the request so that after successful login the user can be directed back to the page he tried to go before logging in.

Comment: Thanks. Is there something I may do in order to prevent this?